# Qt Creator can't find missing libraries

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qt-creator, qmake

I have referenced the following libraries, but Qt Creator v3.0.1 can't seem to find them.

`LIBS += -lueye_api \
         -lcv \
         -lhighgui`

**Is it that the libraries have been deprecated? Are there any replacements for these three libraries?**

I've google searched my problem and found what may be a start. Is `-lopencv_core` a suitable replacement for `-lcv` and is `-lopencv_highgui` a suitable replacement for `-lhighgui`?

Answer (score 0):

When the library the project refers to cannot be found in the same directory as .pro file it is practical to refer to other libraries somehow relative to project file directory.

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../third-party -lother
```

Where the project file directory is located relative to third-party like that:

```
../project
../third-party
```

and the other.lib is in:

```
../third-party/other.lib
```

Or you just need to provide the path to libraries you use somehow.